# How can I change my career path from finance to Web or App development

Tags: software-industry, job-search, career-development, job-change

I have 7 years of experience in investment banking and a degree in Bachelor of Arts.

I'm at the stage in my life were I would like to start a family, move away from the city, and work from home/ free lance, and my current career path would not be able to offer the flexibility.

I would like to change fields to programming. I'm not looking to make a lot of money doing this, I would be the second income in the family and we live a simple life.  Work relating to App development or website development see like a good fit.

Without having to go back to university, where can I go to get fast track training that is actually beneficial?

What sites can I go to to check for jobs that meet this description, so that I can check for the requirements they need?

Comment: You cannot get good paying jobs taking crash course on web app dev.   No more than I could take a crash course and be a investment banker.

Comment: Sorry if I left that impression, I am not looking to make a lot of money. I would be the second income in the family, I would be doing small jobs on the side.

Comment: Also anyone analytical could do well in investment banking as a junior. It involves a lot of on the job learning and proficiency in excel and powerpoint. The downside is your skills are not that useful outside the corporate world unless you start your own business.

Comment: Do you have any idea what languages or areas you'd like to work in?

Comment: If you are looking for second money off hours then paint houses, mow yards, tend bar on weekends, pet sit ...   Really.   No one is looking for an off hour self trained web developer.

Comment: I would like to learn Java for android app development. I also have built websites with ecommerce feature using concert5 but no programming was involved, so it would be great to learn the underlying language.

Comment: @Frisbee If there really is no one then it would be good to know now, although I am under the impression that it is a growing field. I would also like the idea of building my own apps for the marketplace without paying upfront development costs out of pocket.

Comment: It is a growing field.  You really think you can build apps that sell?  You think I could open hedge fund?

Comment: If you want to give it a try, there's a site called CodingBat that will give you some very simple to very challenging examples to practice with. You can also use this site for some other resources: http://codecondo.com/learn-java-programming-10-ways/

Comment: @jim_halpert thanks! I will definitely invest some time into this to see if I have the aptitude for it. I have some experience with vba for Excel macros from self learning, hopefully it is similar.

Comment: @Frisbee I don't know, hence this is why i want to free lance as well. I'm also quite young so career change is not too much of a stretch. I just remember university being slow paced, expensive, and lacking in many real world content. Prob not the same for computer sci though.

Comment: http://abstrusegoose.com/249 sums up my feelings on your question.

Comment: @djechlin I love it haha. The worst that can happen is that I end up with a working knowledge of coding and a side hobby.

Answer (score 4):

**A crash course; probably not.  But self-education.  Sure.**

It worked for me.

Before I started programming professionally I was a waiter.  I had some college education in an unrelated field (though there are parallels) and I needed things to change.

So I stayed up after work every night and worked on HTML/CSS/Javascript.  I knew nearly nothing about those technologies other than that's what powered websites.  I also themed Wordpress sites.  I took small jobs on Wordpress for friends and family and started using that as a portfolio.  I got enough sites for a small portfolio and started marketing myself as a junior front-end developer.  I threw my info up on every careers page (some are much better than others), created an extensive LinkedIn profile and waited a long time.  Eventually recruiters started calling me with entry-level positions.  It felt like an eternity but it could have been about 6 months (of waiting) before getting any real interest.

Where you're coming from, you probably won't make much considering what you may make now.  Be prepared to work on your craft before you start seeing a difference.  The real money in development comes from experience, not just the tech stack.  Someone who really knows their mainframe technology can still make good money in 2016.  Because their time works harder for their company.

**Once I got in with development, and proved some sort of worthy existence, I was fine.**  The hard part was getting in.  Once I started I was able to negotiate and move up to a salary position (This field is contract-to-hire, predominantly, especially what you're interested in), move around and learn more.

I didn't stop there.  Every time I felt like I was stagnant, I moved again; making my intentions obvious to employers about what I knew, where I was going, and what I wanted to do.  This allowed me to get closer to the full-stack developer position I was going for.

But don't do it because it seems easier.  It's very easy to get into a place that wants you to work forever, under extremely tight deadlines, and without much remorse.  It's not always easier, and things do get under the gun.  When Amazon is having issues with a site or app, you can bet your butt the developers behind it (contract or not) are working 24/7 to get it resolved, in extreme conditions and without seeing their families.  The trick is finding the sweet-spot.  **Sounds like work-life balance is important to you, and that's always important to remember when considering potential positions.**

Also be prepared to teach yourself until you retire.  In Web development (or Mobile Apps, etc.) you must always keep up with the technology.  And boy does it change.  A lot.  Be prepared to use almost nothing from one year to the next.  The experience really comes in problem solving; not knowledge of one technology over another.

Most job postings contain little underlying technology required.  Those employers assume you know that stuff.  The requirement might say "SPA".  That means Single Page Application.  Which means a more modern way to work through an application.  That means Javascript knowledge.  Which also means some sort of Javascript framework knowledge.  Which means an understanding of REST (Representation State Transfer)... *etc.*

Instead focus on what you want to do, find the foundation of how that works/how it's built and start building.  Without and work experience you're worth nothing, but showing someone how you make something, how you solve problems, and your knowledge of the foundation which you can only learn by doing; is where real employer interest comes from.

---

For web development there's tons of resources online.  It's up to you to harness them.  When I was cutting my teeth on it, I used [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com), [Udemy](http://udemy.com), [Code Academy](https://www.codecademy.com/), [Treehouse](http://teamtreehouse.com), and StackOverflow.  As well as 100,000+ google searches.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer. It's really encouraging to see how far you've come. My desire is to learn a hard skill on which I can build on, rather than relying mostly on soft skills (which I'm not very good at). I am analytical and problem solving oriented, which seems like it would translate well. The time pressure in some mission critical jobs would not be a good fit for me, but if I steer away from these and stick to some smaller jobs, I hope I could make it work.

Comment: You can definitely do it.  I was never considered "smart" but had a genuine interest in it when I got started.  Just take it slow, and build up your skills everything comes from something; start there and get a good idea of it before continuing.

Comment: @ShawnStrickland: Interesting memoir.  How long did it take before being a developer was your "day job", and not just side gigs for family & friends?

Comment: Probably that estimate of 6 to 8 months. I was a stay at home dad until around 9 months so I did have opportunities to work some during the day. But anyone with kids will know that doesn't really happen easily. I'd say 6 to 8 months of honing a portfolio, talking to recruiters, and getting my first contractor position full-time.

Comment: I'll try to edit that for clarity. Asia reading over it again it's pretty sporadic.

Comment: It depends on the country. In France, it would be nigh-on impossible. I guess this story is US-based. I wish our managers would learn a lot from that kind of stories...

Comment: @gazzz0x2z Why would this story be impossible in France?

Comment: The only way this is impossible is because one doesn't get a degree in the field.  This is surely a problem for many industries, but more and more CS-focused career fields are looking outside of CS degrees to fill talent.  This is probably because those who have proved they can teach themselves tend to do better in this career (as it's always evolving) and it's really based off of what you've done, especially in the front-end sense where a big client in your portfolio makes up for any schooling you *didn't* take.

Comment: Sure, there are CS-based careers that still want a CS degree, and they'll make that obvious in their pre-screening, but most people who put "Computer Science Degree or work-based equivalent" are really just trying to filter out those who are not confident that what they've learned isn't equivalent to what a college would teach you.  Which honestly, especially for web development, colleges don't keep up with trending and in-demand skills like a third-party resource like CodeSchool, CodeAcademy, etc. would.

Comment: I took one CS class in college and their HTML "module" was still using tables for layout.  **Tables for layout!**  Responsive, bootstrap, flexbox (in it's infancy) wasn't even on the radar.  *Things people actually use*.  That's the problem with colleges these days...

Comment: @Brandin : because in France, (1) we have the cult of the diploma, and (2) the number of people who exit the school system with a "software engineer" diploma is huge. Not all deserve the diploma, but it's not a problem to the french recruiter, who just wants someone with the right degree. The recruiter is usually not the project manager(a shame), that's the ultimate reason. I'd love to see more french recruiters understand what Shawn Strickland said.

Comment: @gazzz0x2z I'd love to see more American recruiters understand what I just said!  In instances where I've reviewed resumes before a potential recruit has come in; more than half of them are not an obvious fit skills-wise.